# Cannot get PHP query to return resource to be made into array, I do not have access to connection data

Tags: php, mysql

This is for a self test for a college job application so I am not necessarily looking for the exact statement I need, instead I am trying to get a hint as to what direction to look, I DO NOT have access to the actual database to view it:

This problem tasks us with getting some info on a user when given a NetID($user) and clear-text password($password).  If the md5-hash of $password matches the Passwrd field for the given user, then display the user's UserID.

I am getting hung up using mysql_query, I feel like that is failing because it doesn't return any value that prints on the screen.
I think I have to us mysql_query not mysqli_query because the latter requires a connection, and in the instruction it says the connection all done for me, so I have no info to put into the connect command.

Here's my code:

```
<?
function checkPass($user, $password)
{
    // You will likely want to use mysql_query($query) AND mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    // YOUR CODE HERE

    $md5Password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT interview_user_info.UserID,
        FROM interview_user_info 
        WHERE interview_user_info.Passwd = '$md5Password'";

    $escapedQuery = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    $queryResult = mysql_query($escapedQuery);
    $rowArray = mysql_fetch_array($queryResult, 'MYSQL_NUM');
    $UserID = $rowArray[0];

    return $UserID;

}
?>
```

Here is the text and table info from the page:

---

```
int checkPass ( string $user , string $password )
```

> Write a PHP function "checkPass" that takes two arguments: $user and $password and returns the UserID if the password matches the MD5 encoding of the appropriate password in the interview_user_info table below and -1 otherwise.
>
> The $user variable contains the NetID of the individual; the $password variable contains a clear-text version of the password as submitted.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| interview_user_info                                                             |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------+
| UserID    | LastName    | FirstName | NetID  | Passwd                           |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------+
| 469562029 | Gonzalez    | Shauntee  | sgonz  | 530b4a0ae65148d112537bc0eafba9c9 |
| 702930431 | Bates       | Austin    | abates | 9cdfb439c7876e703e307864c9167a15 |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------+
```

The connection and database selection are taken care of. Write the query to pull data from the table "interview_user_info", and return the result. The connection will be closed for you.

Hint: You will likely need to make use of the following functions and possibly others: md5, mysql_query, mysql_fetch_assoc

---

Comment: why i wouldent hire you: md5 on password, mysql_* useage,

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific?  I was assuming I needed to use md5($password) in order to format it the same way it is formatted in the database, and I wasn't sure I could use mysqli_ as it requires a connection that I cannot give.

Comment: mysql_* needs a database connection too

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing specially not using MD5(). PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: It says on the php page for md5: `Warning
It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm. See the Password Hashing FAQ for details and best practices.` http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Comment: If the college are using MD5 to protect passwords, maybe you application should just say, _I can teach your people some sensible security practices_

Comment: HINT: Dont use the password in the SELECT, just use the NETID. Then check the database hash against your `MD5()` hash of the plain text password that is passed as a parameter

Comment: Also use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_` and parameterised query

Comment: I will certainly look into the use of prepared statements, but if my query syntax is correct shouldn't using mysql_query still return a resource that can be turned into an array even if it's done in bad form?

Comment: Also, unless I am reading incorrectly you need to establish an mysqli object using server name, database, password, etc; I have no access to any of that data to be able to set up a mysqli object, is there a way around this?

Comment: You're running the entire query string through `mysql_real_escape_string()`. That function is meant to escape specific parameter values. Using it on the SQL query string will render it useless. You should check [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-error.php) to find out exactly what went wrong

Comment: Looks like OP is doing a course or class that is about 5 years out-of-date. I don't think suggestions about using alternatives to `mysql_*` and MD5 are going to help as it seems they're locked in to specific constraints. @JGoss just make sure you check the return value from `mysql_query()` and if `false`, check for errors. See http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-query.php#refsect1-function.mysql-query-examples

Comment: THANKS PHIL!  Your comment on the escape_string was the issue, I'll have to read up on how to only escape the parts I need, I just got rid of the escape all together for this problem though.

Comment: Always [read the fine manual](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php#refsect1-function.mysql-real-escape-string-examples). They have examples for a reason. You shouldn't need it for an MD5 hash though as there won't be any unsafe characters.